# Rubocop Offense: Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison

Tags: ruby, rubocop

My Rubocop offense is telling me I need to 'Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison'

While I tried fixing it, it gave me another offense that my 'method line is too long'.

I've tried refactoring to another method but my code broke.

How do I shorten or refactor this code ?

```rb
HSH = { 'a' => 'z', 'b' => 'y', 'c' => 'x', 'd' => 'w', 'e' => 'v', \
        'f' => 'u', 'g' => 't', 'h' => 's', \
        'i' => 'r', 'j' => 'q', 'k' => 'p', 'l' => 'o', 'm' => 'n' }.freeze


def encoder(str)
  encoded_string = ''
  str.chars.each do |char|
    encoded_string = if HSH.key?(char) then encoded_string += HSH[char]
                     elsif HSH.invert.key?(char) then encoded_string += HSH.invert[char]
                     else encoded_string += char
                     end
  end
  encoded_string
end
```

When I ran my test suite, everything was ok.

But the rubocop offense gave me method line is too long.

Comment: Did Robocop disparage your algorithm for coding secret messages as being, er, less than impenetrable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No hash:

```
ALPHABET = ("a".."z").to_a.join

def encoder(str)
  str.tr(ALPHABET, ALPHABET.reverse)
end
```

Comment: Future readers: this answer **is the best here and should be chosen**.

Answer (score 2):

```
HSH = {
  'a' => 'z', 'b' => 'y', 'c' => 'x',
  'd' => 'w', 'e' => 'v', 'f' => 'u',
  'g' => 't', 'h' => 's', 'i' => 'r',
  'j' => 'q', 'k' => 'p', 'l' => 'o',
  'm' => 'n'
}.freeze

def encoder(str)
  str.chars.map { |char| HSH[char] || HSH.invert[char] || char }.join
end
```

Comment: You are computing `HSH.invert` for each character of the string. Also, whenever `chars` is the receiver of an `Enumerable` method (here `map`) I suggest you use `each_char` instead, to avoid the creation of the temporary array `str.chars`.

Answer (score 2):

**NB! Do not use this answer!** the proper way to go is provided by @steenslag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55794669/2035262).

Use the hash with all the letters explicitly mapped *and* the default proc:

```
HSH =
  (?a..?z).zip((?a..?z).to_a.reverse).to_h.
  tap { |h| h.default_proc = ->(_, k) { k }}.
  freeze

def encoder(str)
  str.chars.map(&HSH.method(:[])).join
end
```

Comment: Is this for an obfuscation contest? I would not approve any pull request that came my way with code difficult to read as this.

Comment: @DavidHempy I do not work in teams where this code is considered to be hard-to-read, so that is a win-win.

Comment: I apologize for my snarky comment.

Comment: You forgot a final `join`. @David, I had a laugh over your comments, not the comments themselves but the fact that you apologised for the earlier one, but LEFT it! (Please leave them for others to enjoy.) btw, I did not find mudsie's answer opaque. I was able to figure it out in well under an hour.

Comment: Maybe `str.gsub(/./, HSH)`. This is more efficient than @steenslag's answer in that a linear search is not required for each character.

Answer (score 1):

As with @Steenslag's answer, there's no need to convert the string to an array, map each element of the array and join the result back into a string. The following is defined to be efficient, by avoiding the need for a linear search for each letter.

```
def encode_decode(str)
  rng = 'a'..'z'       
  str.gsub(/./) { |c| rng.cover?(c) ? (219-c.ord).chr : c }
end

plain_text = "The launch code is 'Bal3De8Rd0asH'."
  #=> "Tsv ozfmxs xlwv rh 'Bzo3Dv8Rw0zhH'."
coded_text = encode_decode(plain_text)
  #=> "Tsv ozfmxs xlwv rh 'Bzo3Dv8Rw0zhH'." 
encode_decode(coded_text)
  #=> "The launch code is 'Bal3De8Rd0asH'."
```

Answer (score 1):

Several of us suggested better ways to implement your `encoder` method. But all of us (myself included) didn't actually answer your question, or see a central problem in your code:

> My Rubocop offense is telling me I need to 'Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison'
>
> While I tried fixing it, it gave me another offense that my 'method line is too long'.

```
encoded_string = if HSH.key?(char) then encoded_string += HSH[char]
                 elsif HSH.invert.key?(char) then encoded_string += HSH.invert[char]
                 else encoded_string += char
                 end
```

You sort of followed Rubocop's advice...you assigned a conditional result to a value...but I think you missed the mark. I'm not even sure that's the conditional result it was referring to. I'm assuming you added the `encoded_string = ...` assignment.

That is a uselesss assignment, as you already appended the character to encoded_string within the `if` blocks. You don't have to assign it again.

Rewinding to what I'm guessing was your version 1 code, here's a more efficient way to follow Rubocop's advice. Don't make an assignment within each condition...only do one assignment, with the result of the conditionals:

```
encoded_string += if HSH.key?(char) then HSH[char]
                  elsif HSH.invert.key?(char) then HSH.invert[char]
                  else char
                  end
```

That ends up with less code, and matches your original coding style and approach. It might even make Rubocop happy. The next step to lovely code would be to eliminate the excessive `key?` tests:

```
encoded_string += if HSH[char] then HSH[char]
                  elsif HSH.invert[char] then HSH.invert[char]
                  else char
                  end
```

From there, it's a small step to eliminate the `if/elsif` blocks with `||`'s. And while we're at it, we'll change `+=` to `<<` to avoid, "produce a gazillion of intermediate unnecessary String instances." (Thanks for the suggestion, @Aleksei Matiushkin )

```
encoded_string << HSH[char] || HSH.invert[char] || char
```

For your approach to this problem, that's about the minimal level of conciseness and readability that production code should strive for. Anyone can understand it without thinking real hard or hitting Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please do not suggest `String#+` in the answer, suggest `String#<<` instead. I understand the intent to change as few codes as possible, but it’s a thousand times more offensive to produce a gazillion of intermediate unnecessary `String` instances than to have a line of the length some automatic tool is not satisfied with.

Comment: Thanks, @AlekseiMatiushkin ! Done.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and expand your hash to all 26 letters, so you can avoid the inverse lookup. That simplifies your code by removing one case, which will may appease Rubocop... But more importantly, you'll be using the hash index for greater efficiency and performance. Inverse hash lookups are expensive, as it must read (up to) every value.

Consider encoding "1+2”. It will do three quick index scans, then three full array scans, just to return the original string.

With a fully populated hash, it would only take three quick scans.

Here is your original code with minimal changes to meet your goal:  (There are shorter ways to do this (hint: `tr` or `map`), but shorter is not as important as easy and comfortable to the programmer using the code.)

```
translation = { 
  'a' => 'z', 'b' => 'y', 'c' => 'x', 'd' => 'w', 'e' => 'v', 'f' => 'u', 'g' => 't', 
  'h' => 's', 'i' => 'r', 'j' => 'q', 'k' => 'p', 'l' => 'o', 'm' => 'n', 'n' => 'm', 
  'o' => 'l', 'p' => 'k', 'q' => 'j', 'r' => 'i', 's' => 'h', 't' => 'g', 'u' => 'f', 
  'v' => 'e', 'w' => 'd', 'x' => 'c', 'y' => 'b', 'z' => 'a'
}.freeze

def encoder(str)
  encoded_string = ''

  str.chars.each do |char|
    encoded_string << translation[char] || char
  end
  encoded_string
end
```

You might even consider expanding the hash to upper and lower case letters, or even all 256 char values, depending on what problem you're solving. But let's agree to ignore Unicode chars!

Back to Rubocop... The easiest, sure-fire solution to any sort of "too long/too complex" warning is to pull code out to a new method. Write `def charswap` and use that as the body of your loop. That will make writing tests easier, to boot. But, by expanding your translation array to all 26 letters, the code gets so simple that refactoring isn't really needed.

Comment: You are abusing iteration for reducing, making readers to wonder why `each` was chosen here. The reducing should be done with `Enumerable#reduce` (or `Enumerable#each_with_object`): `def encoder(str); str.chars.each_with_object('') { |char, acc| acc << .... }; end`. Using `each` here is both semantically incorrect and very misleading.

Comment: I agree. But, I'm answering the OP's specific question, with regard to THEIR code. I'm not trying to show how much better I could write it myself.